# AppListEntry.LaunchAsync vs Launcher.LaunchUriAsync

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, launching-application

I want to know the difference between [AppListEntry.LaunchAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.core.applistentry.launchasync?view=winrt-20348) and [Launcher.LaunchUriAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync?view=winrt-20348)

From **AppListEntry.LaunchAsync** documentation

> Launch the app associated with this AppListEntry.
>
> The app is launched without passing parameters. It is launched in the same way as if the
> user clicked on the entry in the app list.

From **Launcher.LaunchUriAsync** documentation:

> Starts the default app associated with the URI scheme name for the
> specified URI.

**Launcher.LaunchUriAsync** launched **without passing parameters** is this the only difference ?

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0):

Passing params or not is an important difference...
If you want to open an external URI in the default browser the only way is `Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(websiteUri)`.
Many of deeplink have params, and for that the `LaunchUriAsync` is the only way to be opened.